# Change class with JQuery to all items with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of checkboxes with the same structure, but they are spans, not selects, so the way they appear to be checked is by adding a class.

```
<div class="mod_6">
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <span class="checkbox" id="AllColors"></span>
        <span>All</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox checked"></span>
          <span>Blue</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Black</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Red</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
function CheckBox() {
    $(".checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
        }
    });
};
```

What I want is, if I click on a specific checkbox, in this case, the one that says 'All' (I assume I should give it an id), I want all the items with the checkbox to be modified and added the class 'checked'. I don't know how to find them as they are in different divs.

What I have tried unsuccessfully is to use find() and then addClass():

```
 $("#allColors").click(function () {
    $.each('.checkbox-wrapper').find('.checkbox').addClass('checked');
})
```

Thank you :)

Comment: in your #allClolors handler use this line ` $('.checkbox-wrapper').find('.checkbox').addClass('checked');` Basically just remove the `each`

Comment: `$('.checkbox')` should select all elements with class checkbox, no matter the parent. `$('.checkbox').addClass('checked')` should add the checked class without further need for code

Comment: why you wrapped your Js code into function `CheckBox` just put inside the document ready.

Comment: @marta see my answer to understand what you was missing :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make it like this if I remember correctly:

```
$('#AllColors').click(function(){
    $('.checkbox-wrapper > .checkbox').addClass('checked')
})
```

Comment: What does "IIRC" mean?

Comment: @bassxzero  IIRC = If I Remember Correctly

Comment: @bassxzero yep, "If I Remember Correctly", but I better edit it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this with `toggleClass()`:

```js
$("#AllColors").click(function (){
  $(".checkbox").toggleClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.checked{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mod_6">
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <span class="checkbox" id="AllColors">All</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox checked"></span>
          <span>Blue</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Black</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Red</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or with `addClass()`:

```js
$("#AllColors").click(function (){
  $(".checkbox").addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.checked{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mod_6">
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <span class="checkbox" id="AllColors">All</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox checked"></span>
          <span>Blue</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Black</span>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Red</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only thing here - looks like toggle `toggleClass` unchecks class which been checked (in case you checked smth before check `All`)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues here:

- you are using `#allColors` instead of `#AllColors`
- you are using `each` in the wrong way
- better use `on()` instead of `click()`

use this instead:

```
$("#AllColors").on('click', function(){
    $('.checkbox-wrapper').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.checkbox').addClass('checked')
    })
})
```